# Storing Graphs in Ethereum to detect Changes

Tags: solidity, storage, graphs

I am new in Blockchain and keep learning and experimenting with Ethereum and Solidity. Yet my knowledge is not enough to know whether the following scenario can be implemented with Ethereum.  The scenario is as follows:

We have some graphs stored in a database. Each graph consists of nodes and edges. We want to store the graphs in Ethereum, to check if a graph has been changed. Lets assume every block contain one graph. We could check if a graph has changed, by comparing the hash of the graph with the previous version in the blockchain. Would this work? Does the hash of a block only depends on the stored data, e.g. the graph?

Answer (score 0):

I had actually done something similar a few months back.

I stored the entire timetable into smartContracts I deployed on my local blockchain.

In your case, I assume you would like to store graph database data in blockchain.(To write it into the storage of smartContract).

However, you don't need to compare hashes of blocks or something like that. We have smartContracts to take care of such lowLevel stuff.

Instead, you need to get stronger with solidity and figure out how to best write smartContracts that can do what you require of them. (In this case storing graph data and making sure you know who/when modified them).

If you are new and you are exploring Solidity && SmartContracts, I would advise you to go over tutorials made by [SmartContractProgarmer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJWh7F3AFyQ_x01VKzr9eyA), he has excellent free resources.